# Janina kolkiewicz who faced Lazarus phenomenon

Tags: human-biology, brain, medicine

I've just read about [Janina kolkiewicz](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-30048087) case who faced Lazarus phenomenon and I was wondering how could her brain and organs survive these long hours without oxygen?

Comment: How far did you get looking for this answer yourself?

Comment: Your question is unclear as it assumes knowledge of a case involving a particular person. You can assume knowledge of biology, but not of this sort of thing. You must describe it and give references.

Comment: Without oxygen, she would not have survived. Granted, she didn't need a lot in her reduced metabolic state.